# How to tricky rank SAS?

Tags: sas

SO For example I have data like this,

```
KEY  first count

11Y    1
11Y    2
11N    3
11N    4
11Y    5
11N    6
```

I want out put like this

```
    KEY  first count  RANKS

    11Y    1          1
    11Y    2          1
    11N    3          2
    11N    4          2
    11Y    5          3
    11N    6          4
```

how can I do in SAS?

Thanks

I did this

```
proc sort data=step3;
by first_count key;
run;

data step4;
set step3;
by key;
if first.key THEN ranks=1;
else ranks+1;
run;
```

This causing error

ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.STEP3

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: @StuSztukowski Hi, I added what I did, you know how to do? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need NOTSORTED.

```
data key;
   input KEY:$3. count;
   cards;
11Y    1
11Y    2
11N    3
11N    4
11Y    5
11N    6
;
run;
data key2;
   set key;
   by key NOTSORTED;
   if first.key then rank+1;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on DN's anwser, You can do it without `first.var` statement.

```
data key;
   input KEY:$3. count;
   cards;
11Y    1
11Y    2
11N    3
11N    4
11Y    5
11N    6
;
run;
data key2;
   set key;
   rank + (key ^= lag(key));
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```